# On which day of the week Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) performed his only Hajj?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, hajj

I was wondering on which day of the week Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) performed his only Hajj?

Comment: Dul-Hijjah 8, 10 was probably Thursday. There is a date converter on [IslamicFinder](http://www.islamicfinder.org/).

Comment: This question shows absolutely no research effort.  What if any attempts have you made to actually find the answer yourself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of low quality

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't add much to the community.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to Islam.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it adds no value to the community.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't add much to the community.

Comment: I'm not voting to close this. Although the asker could have done more research, stackexchange questions are often the first result on search engines and could be good resource for the future.

Comment: @Farhan that would be a great answer!

Answer (score 2):

The first day of Hajj was **Thursday** if we consider the narration from Umar ibn al-Khattab that the [Day of Arafat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_Arafah) was on Friday as recorded in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/38) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/56/4).

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any text which pointed out its precise day. But I found another related information which probably can help you to reach its number. (Hopefully)

**The prophet (S) (5days before Zil-Qa’dah) moved from Medina on Monday. The apostle of Allah (pbuh) entered Mecca at the fourth day of the month. He (S) directly went to the mosque, then went to start the Haj…**

*(Note: I could found the mentioned information. So, I hope you could use them to find its precise day (by calculating the info. above.*

---

**Source:**

- [www.pajoohe.com](http://www.pajoohe.com/fa/index.php?Page=definition&UID=35078)